# Rally Dashboard 'My Defects' App result order

Tags: rally

I use the stock My Defects application on my Rally dashboard. (I'm a developer if it matters.)

I would like to change the Order that the results are displayed in from merely State to State and LastUpdateDate.

I've been searching Rally help and Google for an answer but I haven't been able to find one.

I've tried placing

```
State, LastUpdateDate
```

in the Order field but that doesn't appear to work.

Thanks -
Brian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the space and you should be all set:

```
State,LastUpdateDate
```